# it shows as plain text the transformed xml in browser

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

there is render problem or something else in my browsers(?) with xml transformation so i have this `book.xml` document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xsl"?>
<books>
  <book title="AA" price="1"/>
  <book title="AB" price="3"/>
  <book title="AC" price="6"/>
</books>
```

and want to transform with following `book.xsl` document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <books>
        <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
          <book>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></title>
            <price><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></price>
          </book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </books>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the browser `firefox`,`IE`,`Chrome` show like a plain text:

`AA 1 AB 3 AC 6`
How can force output to xml? `xsl:output method="xml"` not working?

Comment: What kind of rendering do you expect for an unknown XML format? XML to XML transformation in the browser makes sense if you transform to XHTML and/or SVG and/or MathML the browser knows to render but otherwise you get the text nodes rendered without any semantics.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the browsers are able to show an XML view of an XML document (without an associated stylesheet), so it is reasonable to expect that they could also give an XML view of an XML document which is a transformation result.

Comment: @wero, I think Opera used to do that, but others don't. And those XML views also differ vastly between browser when it comes to rendering stuff like doctypes, CDATA section so. As for the current result of XML to XML transformation, I don't think it is plain text, it is the rendering of an unstyled DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen). Browsers are made to display HTML content and not XML content like aspired by you. Modern browsers don't seem to be capable of this usage scenario.

In fact, the XML+XSLT scenario seems to be generally disdained for whatever reason.

I don't understand that either / I do understand that that very well.

IMHO this approach is far superior to the current state of the WWW. Transforming XML files with XSLT to XHTML-5(not really existent) client-side would have been a tremendous improvement to Web-technology.

- Technologically this would have been great for everyone.
- Commercially this would have been disastrous, because it would have eliminated Big-Data efficiently.

Guess who won...

So, returning to answering your question:
Browsers do render HTML, so set `<xsl:output method="html" ... />` and surround your output with HTML tags like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <body>
       <table border="1">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="books/book" />
       </table>
     </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <tr>                                                                    <!-- changed from <books> -->
      <td width="100" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></td>   <!-- changed from <title> -->
      <td width="60"  align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td>   <!-- changed from <price> -->
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template will give you a result being displayed well on modern browsers (Enable NoScript rules for `file:///`!).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XML to XML transformation in the browser then it mostly makes sense for result formats like XHTML and/or SVG and/or MathML that browsers know to render. For unknown, arbitrary XML formats the browsers don't do anything but render the unstyled result tree, so basically the text nodes. I think only Opera used to apply its collapsible XML source view rendering to the XML transformation result.

In other browsers, to have some visually meaningful rendering, you can apply CSS to the result document, as done in https://martin-honnen.github.io/js/2017/test2017022801.xml where I have used your XSLT code and adapted it to output a processing instruction `xml-stylesheet` to associate a CSS stylesheet with the transformation result elements, basically rendering your `books` result as a table with `book` elements forming the rows and the child elements forming the cells.

So the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/css" href="test2017022801.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <books>
        <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
          <book>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></title>
            <price><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></price>
          </book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </books>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where the CSS is

```
books {
    margin: 1em;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
book {
    display: table-row;
}
title, price {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2pt;
}
```

and then all four browsers I have tried (current versions of IE, Edge, Firefox, Chrome on Windows 10) render the XML result data as a table.

In my view, however, it makes more sense and is easier to do to simply transform the XML to HTML elements with the semantics and rendering you want instead of trying to style XML with CSS similar to HTML.